# In connected motion, arent the tension of string and weight of body action and reaction forces? so shouldnt they be equal in magnitude?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics

[image]

I cant comprehend how the tension on the string become less when the body is accelerated downwards?

Answer (score 1):

No they are not action and reaction forces.  The action -reaction principle manifests in the fact that the force the string exerts on the block is equal and opposite to the force the block exerts on the string.

Also, the weight of the block is due to the gravitational pull off the earth. The reaction to that is the force the block exerts on the earth (which has an absolutely negligible effect and is ignored in the problem).

It isn't the case that the block accelerates which causes the string tension to be less than $mg$. Rather it is the best that the tension is less than the weight which leaves a net force acting on the block, causing it to accelerate.

Comment: "The action -reaction principle manifests in the fact that the curve the string exerts on the block is equal and opposite to the force the block exerts on the string." Do you mean force instead of curve?

Comment: Yes I do, thanks. Fixed. Damn you, predictive keyboard.

Comment: um... is the tension on either side of the pulley going to be equal? or will the same string experience 2 different tension forces?

Comment: @FatimahRashid If the pulley is considered to be massless, then the string on either side will have the same tension. If, however, the pulley mass cannot be ignored, then the tension must be different on each side. This is because we now need a net torque to rotate the pulley.